# Gradle Error 2 in Android project even file exists

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've generated android project with gradle support in IntelliJ. I have arch linux, on my friend's computer who has Windows everything is ok. On my computer I cannot build project, I get following error:

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> /home/hubert/IdeaProjects/AGHacks/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/hubert/bin/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.0.1/aapt": error=2,  No such file or directory

And both file exists:

```
➜  IdeaProjects  ls -al /home/hubert/IdeaProjects/AGHacks/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 hubert hubert 188 Oct 22 22:51 /home/hubert/IdeaProjects/AGHacks/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/21.0.0/res/drawable-xhdpi/abc_list_selector_disabled_holo_light.9.png

➜  IdeaProjects  ls -al /home/hubert/bin/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.0.1/aapt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 hubert hubert 1248409 Oct 21 21:29 /home/hubert/bin/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.0.1/aapt`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install 32bit version of libc++ and other applications.